# Golang Undefined Functions

Tags: go

I have the following package src/helpers but when i import it in a different package the only function exported is EmailValidator, but not the other ones, all of them begin with Mayus so i don't know what's happening. thanks

```
package models

import (
    "helpers"
    ...
)

func FindByUsername(username *string) (*User, error) {
    if username == nil || len(*username) == 0 ||
            !helpers.UniqueNamesValidator(*username) {
            return nil, errors.New("Invalid Username")
    }
    ...
}
```

src/models/user.go:88: undefined: helpers.UniqueNamesValidator

but

```
func FindByEmail(email *string) (*User, error) {
    if email == nil || len(*email) == 0 || !helpers.EmailValidator(*email) {
            return nil, errors.New("Invalid Email")
    }
 ...
 }
```

works well

here is the source code.

```
package helpers

import (
    "regexp"
)

const (
    email_key    = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*"
    email_domain = "@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?"
)

func EmailValidator(email string) bool {
    pattern := regexp.MustCompile(email_key + email_domain)
    return pattern.MatchString(email)
}

func UserNamesValidator(name string) bool {
    pattern := regexp.MustCompile(`\A([ña-zA-ZÑ]{3,16} {0,1}){1,3}\z`)
    return pattern.MatchString(name)
}

func UniqueNamesValidator(unique_name string) bool {
    pattern := regexp.MustCompile(`\A\w{4,10}\z`)
    return pattern.MatchString(unique_name)
}

func ProductNameValidator(p_name string) bool {
    pattern := regexp.MustCompile(`\A(\w|\s){4,30}\z`)
    return pattern.MatchString(p_name)
}

func TextOnlyValidator(text string) bool {
    pattern := regexp.MustCompile(`\A(\w+|\s)+\z`)
    return pattern.MatchString(text)
}
```

Comment: Did you recently build helpers? `cd src/helper ; go build`

Comment: yes before building src/models

Comment: when i do it manually it builds well, but i made a Makefile it does the same but doesn't work, any idea?

`GOCMD=go

GOBUILD=$(GOCMD) build

MODELS_DIR=src/models

HELPERS_DIR=src/helpers

all: model helper
 ${GOBUILD}

model:
 $(MAKE) -C $(MODELS_DIR)

helper:
 $(MAKE) -C $(HELPERS_DIR)`

Comment: Could you inverse the order of '`all`' in your Makefile?  `all: helper model`

Comment: What is `MAKE`? Could you simply call go build, as in this Makefile? https://gist.github.com/dnishimura/2961173

Comment: $(MAKE) -C $(DIR) is because i had more Makefiles inside those DIR for modular build, i thought that was the best approach for a big project, i'm learning while i'm coding so excuse my ignorance, i understand part of that gist now is working

`GOCMD=go

GOBUILD=$(GOCMD) build

all:
 $(GOBUILD) $(HELPERS_DIR)
 $(GOBUILD) $(MODELS_DIR)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [illustrated in this Makefile](https://gist.github.com/dnishimura/2961173), and confirmed [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215149/golang-undefined-functions/25215342#comment39273226_25215149), a better definition would be:

```
GOCMD=go 
GOBUILD=$(GOCMD) 
build all: $(GOBUILD) $(HELPERS_DIR) $(GOBUILD) $(MODELS_DIR)
```

Comment: men, i'm having the same problem making the binary executable, if i `go build PACKAGE` works, but when i go build the main package says `models/product.go:53: undefined: helpers.ProductNameValidator` here is the command i used to build `go build helpers &&\
 go build models &&\
 go build handlers &&\
 go build db &&\
 go build -o ciudad-gourmet main.go`